# delete row if it matches a given condition while doing iterrows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe sorted by id, dates1, and with columns id, dates1, dates2, dates3 (three different dates of three different events).

I want to iterate over each row and delete the row if the difference in days for two dates1 of records of the same id (two different records of the same id) is > 10, same for dates2, and same for dates3.

I thought of doing this using a for loop and a temp dictionary to store each id and it's dates, but it's quite inefficient in terms of O(time) and more so O(storage).

This is what I have in mind:

Let us say this is the example data frame

```
e = pd.DataFrame({
    'id':[1,1,1,
          1,2,2,
          2],
    'date1':[datetime.date(2018,10,1),datetime.date(2018,10,1),datetime.date(2018,9,29),
             datetime.date(2010,3,4),datetime.date(2018,12,10),datetime.date(2018,12,4),
             datetime.date(2018,11,29)],
    'date2':[datetime.date(2018,10,3),datetime.date(2018,10,3),datetime.date(2018,9,29),
             datetime.date(2018,9,25),datetime.date(2018,12,10),datetime.date(2018,12,4),
             datetime.date(2015,1,1)],
    'date3':[datetime.date(2018,10,1),datetime.date(2018,10,1),datetime.date(2018,9,27),
             datetime.date(2018,9,23),datetime.date(2018,12,10),datetime.date(2018,12,3),
             datetime.date(2015,1,1)]})
```

Then I'd delete unwanted rows based on previous description w this code.

```
e_dict = {}
for index, row in e.iterrows():
    id = row['id']
if id in e_dict:
    date1_diff = abs((row['date1']-e_dict[id][-1]['date1']).days)
    #print(date1_diff)
    date2_diff = abs((row['date2']-ff_dict[api10][-1]['date2']).days)
    #print(job_end_date_diff)
    date3_diff = abs((row['date3']-ff_dict[api10][-1]['date3']).days)
    #print(date3_diff)
    #print('new row')
    if date1_diff <= 10 and date2_diff <= 10 and date3_diff <= 10:
        # drop current row from df
    if id in e_dict:
        e_dict.append(id)
    else:
        e_dict[id] = [row]
```

And the desired output, i.e., the new output would be:

```
e = pd.DataFrame({
    'id':[1,
          1,2,
          2],
    'date1':[datetime.date(2018,10,1),
             datetime.date(2010,3,4),datetime.date(2018,12,10),
             datetime.date(2018,11,29)],
    'date2':[datetime.date(2018,10,3),
             datetime.date(2018,9,25),datetime.date(2018,12,10),
             datetime.date(2015,1,1)],
    'date3':[datetime.date(2018,10,1),
             datetime.date(2018,9,23),datetime.date(2018,12,10),
             datetime.date(2015,1,1)]})
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, do the reference dates change, or are they always referencing the same values. (I don't see you appending to e_dict).

Comment: @Lzkatz the reference dates don't change.

Comment: @Lzkatz good point.  I forgot that when copying the code

Comment: Can you post your desired output? There is definitely a better way to do this than iterrows

Comment: @chrisz Just changed it with desired output

Answer (score 1):

Using the shift on each data series you can then use this to filter.

```
def diff_zero(ds):
    diff = (ds.shift() - ds).apply(lambda y: y)
    return ~pd.isna(diff) | (diff == 0.0)

def days_diff_less_than(ds, val):
    diff = (ds.shift() - ds).apply(lambda y: y.days).abs()
    return pd.isna(diff) | (diff <= val)

e = e.drop(e[days_diff_less_than(e['dates1'], 10) & diff_zero(e['id'])].index)
e = e.drop(e[days_diff_less_than(e['dates2'], 10) & diff_zero(e['id'])].index)
e = e.drop(e[days_diff_less_than(e['dates3'], 10) & diff_zero(e['id'])].index)

print(e)

#    id      dates1      dates2      dates3
# 0   1  2018-10-01  2018-10-01  2018-10-01
# 3   1  2010-03-04  2010-03-04  2010-03-04
# 4   2  2018-12-10  2018-12-10  2018-12-10
# 6   2  2015-01-01  2015-01-01  2015-01-01
```

If instead, all difference in days need to be less than `10` the code changes to:

```
e = e.drop(
    e[days_diff_less_than(e['date1'], 10) & days_diff_less_than(e['date2'], 10) & days_diff_less_than(e['date3'], 10) & diff_zero(e['id'])].index
)
```

Comment: edited example.  Also, pd.isna does not exist in my pandas version, I am using pd.isnull instead, think it's exactly the same though...

Comment: @proprocastinatrix it was my mistake, it was an and and conditional statemetn, not an or or.  I just changed the answer.

Comment: @proprocastinatry in my larger data i see some problems, still investigating